# SQL: Extract decimal from varchar

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssms

How do I isolate a decimal from a varchar?
Ex. How do I get '97.4' from '97.4N IU/ML'?

Comment: is there any consistent pattern in your strings, such as the numbers are always the first 3 characters?

Comment: Hey David. Yes, the leading characters will always be numbers. My question has been answered, though. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming the number portion will always be at the left you could do

**UPDATED**

Before my solution only extracted the decimal portion of the string, it did no conversion. Furthermore if you are getting bad data there is no guarantee what you're getting in that column, its very possible you could be getting a scientific expression as well so it's best to do an `ISNUMERIC()` test before trying to extract the number. Converting from a string using the type of Float is nice because it will also handle scientific expression but it's never a good idea to store numbers as floats because a float that displays as 2.70 may not equal another float that displays as 2.70 solely because in each instance the system decided to store it with more places of precision, for this reason you should always store numbers in a fixed precision format if you plan on doing any comparisons or math on the value.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(MyColumn VARCHAR(25))
GO

INSERT INTO MyTable(MyColumn)
VALUES
 ('1.23E+10')
,('2.23E+8')
,('2.235432E-6')
,('4 of 40')
,('500mg/day')
,('97.4N IU/ML')
,('No Maximun')
,(NULL)
,('')
,('See Appendix R')
GO

SELECT
  CONVERT(DECIMAL(20,8),
  CASE 
    WHEN IsNumeric(MyColumn)=1 THEN 
      CONVERT(FLOAT,MyColumn)
    ELSE CONVERT(FLOAT,'0'+LEFT(MyColumn,PATINDEX('%[^0-9.]%',MyColumn)-1))
  END) AS MyDecimal
  ,MyColumn
FROM MyTable
```

[New SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dd9b4/1)

**Old Answer**

```
SELECT LEFT('97.4N IU/ML',PATINDEX('%[^0-9.]%', '97.4N IU/ML')-1)
```

so to perform it on a column would look like this

```
SELECT LEFT(MyColumn,PATINDEX('%[^0-9.]%', MyColumn)-1) FROM MyTable
```

You can test (old answer) using this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3aeb0/1)

Comment: Thank you! This was perfect for what I needed. appreciate you taking the time.